# Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer not installing in Visual Studio through NuGet Package Manager

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer Package Source NuGet.org but its showing error:[Error Image NU1301](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ztuu0.png)

What are the possible solutions for that error?

Is there any issues in Package source....?

Comment: Have you tried to lookup [NuGet Error NU1301](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1301)? Did you see that it says, _Restore could not be completed because the listed source is unavailable_? This is probably because both [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/2.0.0) and [Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/2.0.0) have been withdrawn due to security vulnerabilities. Try upgrading your solution to use newer, supported versions of those packages.

Comment: I am using .Net 6.0 and installing latest version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore was resulted in error, successfully installed the 6.0 version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. Its working now!